# .htaccess redirect without colon

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect an application link, but the middle colon (:) was not added. It's probably a simple problem but I couldn't find a solution.

Currently, I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ts3server://ts3.domain.com [R=301,L]
```

Result:

```
http://ts3server//ts3.domain.com
```

Comment: I doubt that that kind of host name is technically _allowed_, so I would not be surprised if this is one of those apache "error correction" features that can't really be disabled.

Comment: The question is _why_ you want to add a colon there. It does not really seem to make much sense. Which is why this question reads like a classical A/B problem. Maybe you want to revise the question (there is an "edit" link below it) and explain what you are actually trying to do ...

Comment: Could it be that by "application link", you actually mean that the URL you want to go to would be `ts3server://ts3.domain.com` - without `http://` in front of it, so that `ts3server` would actually _be_ the protocol name ...?

Comment: Normally there is no "http://" part, that's right. But if I don't add it, it redirects incorrectly like this:
  http://domain.co/home/domain/web/domain.co/public_html/ts3server://ts3.domain.com

I guess it's something that can't be done with just .htaccess.

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated your question with a description of the actual redirect you are trying to perform, since it would seem the _rule_ you've posted does not reflect that (`http` is not the intended protocol it would seem). Also, what you've posted is a many-to-one redirect (every request is redirected to the same target) - is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments, it would seem the intention is to redirect to `ts3server://ts3.domain.com` (`ts3server` is the intended protocol, not `http` as stated in your rule).

In this instance the limitation is mod_rewrite (not Apache per se). `ts3server` is not a protocol that mod_rewrite understands and since the *substitution* string does not start with a slash it is seen as a *relative* URL-path and so (by default) the directory-prefix (ie. `/home/domain/web/domain.co/public_html/`) is added back when constructing the URL to redirect to (in the `Location` header).

The solution is to use a mod_alias `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` directive instead, that doesn't "validate" the protocol.

Your rule appears to suggest that *everything* should be redirected to a single target (many-to-one) - which doesn't look correct, but if that is the intention then use `RedirectMatch`. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ ts3server://ts3.domain.com
```

(Should there be a trailing slash on the end of the target URL?)

Otherwise, if the intention is to redirect `/something` to `ts3server://ts3.domain.com/something` then use a `Redirect` directive instead, that uses simple prefix matching (automatically copying the match onto the end of the target). For example:

```
Redirect 301 / ts3server://ts3.domain.com/
```

(Note the trailing slash on the target - mandatory in this example, otherwise you will get a malformed redirect for anything but requests to the root.)

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing and test first with a 302 (temp) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.